# Implementing Generic, General, Specific and Portable Bitwise Operations

Tags: c, generics, bitwise, c-preprocessor

First my appologies. My mental faculties currently leave rather a lot to be desired and I have thus spend an inordinary amount of time on this pet project of mine, testing myself if you will.
I find it incredible difficult to wrap my head around most of these things I used to be able to do in my sleep, and it is utterly frustrating. Please bear with me. It may not seem like it, but these reasonable simple ideas has taken weeks of relearning and not least trial an error.

The Basic Concept:
A Generic, Generalized and Portable Bitwise library of sorts, or at the very least, answering the question if it is even possible to achieve.
To me at least, this is very usefull, because even now, I do rather enjoy Bittwiddling, because certain thing like Arithmetic and Logical Shift functionality, in princible at least (so I am told), are implementation defined, as per the C standard, and because it is very easy to end up with difficult to track bugs, due to type specifics and such. To my mind it should not be so. (char)b>>d should not depend on the sign bit, unless explicitely specified, in which case the functionality should be dependable and NOT affected by the compiler implementation. Doing otherwise, to me, is not much different than leaving it to the compiler to decide say the order of operations. Certainly, 1+2*3 = 9 is unacceptable. I think not less of the witwise operators, and since I am unlikely to convince anyone to chance these thing on my account, I'd very much like to implement certain functionality myself.

My main interest:
General portability.
Safety, as in "when done right"
Not maintainability.
Blunders I have been unable to indentify myself. There is at least one.
Alternative approaches.
Am I even employing the preprocessor correctly? I haven't emploed it much in the past, or if so I've forgotten.
Is _Generic() the right approach? Am I using it right?
Are there better alternatives?
It would seem that Casting is far more complex than has traditionally been my understanding, and I now see that many of the issues I've had throughout the year, what little I can remember that is, can well be due to this. I suspect there is something fundamental I have not yet understod.
example:

```
printf("%08X\n", (short)0x8001);
printf("%08X\n", (unsigned int)((short)0x8001));
/* stdout: 0xFFFF8001
   printf specifics or general confusion on my part? */
```

Lastly, I am also very interested in tips and trick to convince the compiler to do proper optimization. CLang usually behave without much nuddging, whereas GCC is rather difficult to convinse. For examply both GCC and CLang optimize the Deltaswap Function as well as can be expected and probably as is possible, but GCC insists on 2 extra and quite unneccesary MOV instructions.

I should mention that apart from the test in the posted code, I am working from scratch, freestanding, with no standard library, as part of the exercise, but also to ensure that it is I who make the decisions whereever there may be doubt as to the "right way".
I do however not think it matters much here and didn't want to include a lot of assembly, syscalls etc.

Other than that I hope you can forgive the format. I find this difficult at the best of times, and right now, it is nearly impossible, though it may not seem like it. I am more than willing to make the not insignificant effort to edit and improve on what I'm sure is a bit of a travesty of a post, as per your suggestion.
This post took more than an hour to write initially, naturally not including the code, and the first edit just as long. If nothing else, please respect this.

At any rate, thanks for the attention.

```
#ifndef BITWISE_H
#define BITWISE_H
/* These Work in conjunction with G_T. I would like to find a better solution. */
/* In essence casting to signed T, unsigned T and/or type of T. */
#define G_TO_T(M,T,B) (M T)(B)
#define G_TO_S(M,T,B) (T)(B)
#define G_TO_U(M,T,B) (unsigned T)(B)
/* I have yet to find documentation, that I can comprehend at any rate, as to */
/* how _Generic() actually works, but after much experimentation, I find that */
/* this works, although it seems to that _Generic() is badly implemented.     */
#define G_T(T,B,OP) _Generic((T),\
signed char:        OP(signed,char,B),\
char:               OP(,char,B),\
unsigned char:      OP(unsigned,char,B),\
short:              OP(,short,B),\
unsigned short:     OP(unsigned,short,B),\
int:                OP(,int,B),\
unsigned int:       OP(unsigned,int,B),\
long:               OP(,long,B),\
unsigned long:      OP(unsigned,long,B),\
long long:          OP(,long long,B),\
unsigned long long: OP(unsigned,long long,B))
/* The various Shift Operation, ensuring destinct Logical and Arithmetic      */
/* Shift, as far as this seem possible.                                       */
#define S_SHL(B,D) ((B)<<(D))
/* For completion.                                                            */
#define S_SAL(B,D) SHL(B,D)
#define S_SHR(B,D) (G_T(B,B,G_TO_U)>>(D))
#define S_SAR(B,D) (G_T(B,B,G_TO_S)>>(D))
/* Generalized Logical and Arithmetic Shift                                   */

#define S_LSH(B,D) ((D>0) ? (S_SHL(B,D)) : (S_SHR(B,-(D))))
#define S_ASH(B,D) ((D>0) ? S_SAL(B,D) : S_SAR(B,-(D)))
/* d = width-d, i.e. ((char)b<<<-x) == ((char)b>>>(8-x))                      */
/* I've done it this way for as long as I can remember, but I suspect that it */
/* is not very portable.                                                      */
#define DMASK(B,D) ((sizeof(B)*8-1)&(D))
#define S_ROL(B,D) S_SHL(B,DMASK(B,  D ))|S_SHR(B,DMASK(B,-(D)))
#define S_ROR(B,D) S_SHL(B,DMASK(B,-(D)))|S_SHR(B,DMASK(B,  D ))
/* A bit more complex example implementation of the Delta Swap function.      */
/* For the curious, yet uninformed:                                           */
/* https://www.chessprogramming.org/General_Setwise_Operations#DeltaSwap      */
/* XOP describes the recurring pattern x^LSH(x,delta)                         */
/* I'd very much like to actually use S_LSH, but there's some sort of bug I   */
/* just can't wrap my head around, thus passing OP instead.                   */
#define XOP(B,D,OP) ((B)^OP(B, D))
#define DELTASWAP(B,MASK,DELTA) \
G_T(B,              \
    XOP(            \
       (MASK)&      \
        XOP(        \
            B,      \
            DELTA,  \
            S_SHR   \
        ),          \
    DELTA,          \
    S_SHL           \
)^(B),G_TO_T)

#include <stdio.h>
/* Delta Swap in Action */

void ds_test( void )
{
    short b0 = 0x8000;
    long m0 = 0x0000000000000001L;
    unsigned d0 = 15;
    printf("%hx\n", DELTASWAP(b0,m0,d0) );
    // expect result: 1
    unsigned long long b1 = 0x9696969696969696ULL;
    int m1 = 0x05050505;
    unsigned d1 = 1;
    printf("%llx\n", DELTASWAP(b1,m1,d1) );
    // expected result: 0x9696969699999999
    // conclusion: Apparently working as expected.

}

#endif//BITWISE_H
```